# Improve tikz-error Messages

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

This question is about finding reasons for compile errors when using `tikz`.

Consider the files `compiles.tex`, `compiles-not1.tex` and `compiles-not2.tex`. Then it is clear that `compiles-not1.tex` does not compile, because the name `C` has not been assigned. The file `compiles-not2.tex` does not compile, because `\draw (A) -- (A -| B );` contains a space after the name `B`. However, this is difficult to see from the error message.

Is it possible to tweak the error messages generated by `tikz` to perhaps mark `tikz`-code and names in some way? What I mean is that in the example, an error message `! Package pgf Error: No shape named 'B ' is known.` might be more helpful, as the space in the name `B\␣` (`B` with a trailing space) is more clearly delimited from the message.

File `compiles.tex` compiles without errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) {A};
    \node[above right of=A] (B) {B};
    \draw (A) -- (A -| B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

On compilation `compiles-not1.tex` generates `! Package pgf Error: No shape named C is known.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) {A};
    \node[above right of=A] (B) {B};
    \draw (A) -- (A -| C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`compiles-not2.tex` generates `! Package pgf Error: No shape named B  is known.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) {A};
    \node[above right of=A] (B) {B};
    \draw (A) -- (A -| B );
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to post this as a feature request at https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/?source=navbar?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I assumed that the behavior could be tweaked within `latex` to get the desired result. Not sure though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose it might be useful to make a feature request about this at SourceForge (https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/?source=navbar), but it seems it's possible to patch a macro to achieve this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\pgfpointanchor}{No shape named #1 is known}{No shape named '#1' is known}{}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) {A};
    \node[above right of=A] (B) {B};
    \draw (A) -- (A -| B );
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This will throw the error

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named 'B ' is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9     \draw (A) -- (A -| B )
                              ;
?
```

Comment: I had to do some `grep`ing to find exactly where this error message came from.